# Python defaultdict - get access to fields

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to work with Bittrex API
And I want to store "MarketName, "Last"(price) and "Volume"

```
from collections import defaultdict
bittrex_prices = defaultdict(list)

def get_bittrex_price():
    Prices = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"
    r = requests.get(url=Prices)
    data = r.json()
    for coin in range(0,3):
        bittrex_prices.update({ data['result'][coin]["MarketName"]: [data['result'][coin]["Last"], data['result'][coin]["Volume"]]})

    print(bittrex_prices.items())
```

The output:

```
dict_items([('BTC-2GIVE', [5.7e-07, 2737875.01432421]), ('BTC-ABY', [3.7e-07, 3199768.33293631]), ('BTC-ADA', [1.621e-05, 33765846.49729761])])
```

How can I get a price of 2nd coin or the name of 3rd coin? 
This `bittrex_prices[1]` returns None

Comment: `bittrex_prices` is a dictionary. You should use a key to access an item, not the item's position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `bittrex_prices` in your function first, then call it's key. I'm assuming you want `BTC-ABY`'s price, which is index `0`. See below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
bittrex_prices = defaultdict(list)

def get_bittrex_price():
    Prices = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"
    r = requests.get(url=Prices)
    data = r.json()
    for coin in range(0,3):
        bittrex_prices.update({ data['result'][coin]["MarketName"]: [data['result'][coin]["Last"], data['result'][coin]["Volume"]]})

    print(bittrex_prices.items())
    return(bittrex_prices)


x = get_bittrex_price()

print(x['BTC-ABY'][0])
```

this returns `3.7e-07`